# Format the results fetched by query for display

Tags: java, php, html, mysql, jsp

I have the following `MySQL` query which fetches all the information I need.

```
SELECT biobank.*, organization_.name, biobankattributelists.*
FROM biobank INNER JOIN organization_ ON biobank.biobankDbId = organization_.organizationId 
LEFT JOIN biobankattributelists ON biobank.biobankDbId=biobankattributelists.biobankDbId 
WHERE ((organization_.name LIKE '%%' OR '' IS NULL) 
OR (biobank.biobankId LIKE '%%' OR '' IS NULL) 
OR (biobank.acronym LIKE '%%' OR '' IS NULL) 
OR (biobankattributelists.attributeListName LIKE '%%' OR '' IS NULL) 
OR (biobankattributelists.attributeListValue LIKE '%%' OR '' IS NULL)) 
AND (biobank.countryCode = '' OR '' = '')
```

The result is [image]

The important columns to note here are `biobankDbId, attributeListName, attributeListValue`. Each biobank can have different `attributeListName` and each of that `attributeListName` has different `attributeListValue`. **The combination of these three is unique across the result set**. For eg in the `rows 2 and 3`; **Available Documents** for **Biobank for Serum** are **Protocols/Procedures** and **Sample Catalogue**.

Provided that I get the result like this:

```
Biobank results = BiobankLocalServiceUtil.searchBiobanks();
for(Biobank row:results){
 // To be done....

}
```

**I want the result to be displayed like this for each biobank grouped by the `attributeListName`.**

```
Name: Biobank For Serum

Automation Services:
Analysis

Available Documents:
Protocols/Procedures, Sample Catalogue

Complementary Services:
Biochemistry Laboratory, Pathology Department/Imaging

.....
```

I can probably get this done by fetching the results as it is and again making another query. But it will be inefficient to make multiple queries. Further more since I have everything needed fetched by this query I am looking for the solution either by modifying the query or perhaps in the front end say **PHP/JSP** to format the query result as I want it displayed.

P.S. Apologies for the small picture. It is much bigger if opened in the new tab.

Comment: I don't understand at all what you want : your query is strange : "LIKE '%%' OR '' IS NULL" '' will never be null! The language is php or java ? The answer will be totally different depending of the language. Maybe you can give the object Biobank...

Comment: And what is * OR '' = '' * supposed to do? Suggest bin this and start again!

Comment: Please assume the query to be correct. I am using Liferay Java EE portal framework, and the query is displayed slightly differently. And I use the mysql query log to run the query in sql workbench. As it is this is the empty query with no params which fetches me the result set in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Your query, generated by this Liferay thing you're using, is distractingly bizarre. But it does seem to be correct. Hopefully all those strange `OR '' IS  NULL` clauses don't ruin performance.

You seem to be dealing with a name/value schema in your `biobankattributelists` table.

Your problem here is one of formatting your result set for display. As you point out, all the information you need is in the result set. What you need to do, in your host language (Java? php? we can't tell from your question), is read the result set and construct your output.

If you can modify the query, I suggest you add this `ORDER BY` clause to its end.

```
ORDER BY organization_.name, 
         biobankattributelists.attributeListName,
         biobankattributelists.attributeListValue
```

You want this so the rows of the result set will appear in the order you need them to construct your output.

Then you want to implement, in your host program, what report writing people call *control break logic*. That is, you want to do something special each time the value of a column changes from its previous value.  For example, each time the organization name changes, you want to display the new organization name.

With respect, it's beyond the scope of a SO answer to teach you to do that.